# Sorting a list which has numbers in the form of string in python

Tags: python, python-2.7, sorting

I have list of numbers which is in the form of string and I want to sort the numbers in it. How do I sort such numbers in python?

Here is my list.

```
key_s=['115', '114', '117', '116', '111', '110', '113', '112', '68', '119', '118', '44', '45', '42', '43', '41', '76', '108', '109', '71', '107', '79', '13', '15', '14', '17', '16', '37']
```

I tried using `key_s.sort()`.It returns `None` instead of sorted array. I even tried `sorted(key_s)` which is even not working. So what is the solution to sort it?

Comment: sorted(key_s, key=int) - for more details [read documentation](https://docs.python.org/2/library/functions.html#sorted)

Comment: `map(str, sorted(map(int, key_s)))`?

Comment: @Dhruv: are you trying to win the functional paradigm abuse award there?

Comment: @MartijnPieters Sorry?

Comment: @Dhruv: mapping to int, sorting, then mapping back to string is hugely inefficient. Use `sorted(key_s, key=int)`, no need to map back to strings again, or create 2 intermediate list objects if you are using Python 2.

Comment: @MartijnPieters Thanks.

Answer (score 4):

Yes, `list.sort()` sorts *in place*, and returns `None` to indicate it is the list itself that has been sorted. The `sorted()` function returns a *new* sorted list, leaving the original list unchanged.

Use `int` as a key:

```
sorted(key_s, key=int)
```

This returns a *new* list, sorted by the numeric value of each string, but leaving the type of the values themselves unchanged.

Without a key, strings are sorted *lexicographically* instead, comparing character by character. Thus `'9'` is sorted *after* `'10'`, because the character `'1'` comes before `'9'` in character sets, just like `'a'` comes before `'z'`.

The `key` argument lets you apply a [*Schwartzian_transform*](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Schwartzian_transform), informing the sorting algorithm what to sort by. Each value in the list is sorted according to `key(value)` (so `int(value)` here) instead of the original value itself.

Demo:

```
>>> key_s = ['115', '114', '117', '116', '111', '110', '113', '112', '68', '119', '118', '44', '45', '42', '43', '41', '76', '108', '109', '71', '107', '79', '13', '15', '14', '17', '16', '37']
>>> sorted(key_s, key=int)
['13', '14', '15', '16', '17', '37', '41', '42', '43', '44', '45', '68', '71', '76', '79', '107', '108', '109', '110', '111', '112', '113', '114', '115', '116', '117', '118', '119']
```

Comment: @Martijin Oh alright. Thank you

Comment: Good explanation. up-voted. can you explain more on `key` ?

Comment: @VivekSable: done.